# 14.04 stops booting mid-upstart - how to debug?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

My laptop is fully updated to the latest 14.04 packages, and all of a sudden it just stops coming up during boot:

[image]

(I'm sure you can ignore the `vg_sys-root` at the top)

I booted into recovery, started services by hand so I could get into it then continued the boot sequence. I was then able to get enough things going to get my desktop up and get to work, but some things aren't working (like network manager, etc).

I'm still trying to figure out how to debug upstart, but it seems to me that these signals are still waiting to get processed?

```
 3154 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
 3157 ?        S      0:00  \_ initctl emit startup
 3160 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -e /proc/self/fd/9
 3217 ?        S      0:00  \_ initctl emit plymouth-ready
```

I have a crypted disk, been using this setup for ages.

```
/etc/crypttab:
sda3_crypt UUID=8fc603a9-e199-427f-b079-f273c46856cb none luks
```

Any idea where to go from here or debug upstart and find out what it's waiting for?